# Moving average in negative direction (ma in R forecast)

Tags: r, forecast

For a series

```
X=(x_1,x_2,...x_t-2, x_t-1, x_t)
```

I would like to compute a moving average for each point with respect to the previous k time steps. For example, if k = 2, I want to return:

```
X =(NA, (x_1+x_2)/2 ... (x_t-2 + x_t-3)/2, (x_t-2 + x_t-1)/2, (x_t + x_t-1)/2)
```

If I use the moving average function ma, e.g.

```
ma(X, order = 2, centre = TRUE)
```

I get the average of each point and its neighbor in the positive and negative direction, while setting centre=FALSE calculates the moving average with respect to the positive direction. Is there a simple way to have point t as the running average of (t-k+1...t)?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: For x1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6), I would like to calculate the moving average of a point and its k previous points. If k = 1, the output would be (NA, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5). For k=2, (NA, NA, 2, 3, 4, 5). I don't see a way to do this for arbitrary k using ma in the forecast library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming test input X as shown this takes the mean of the current and prior value. Note the r on the end of rollmeanr which tells it to use the right aligned version rather than the center aligned version.

```
library(zoo)

X <- 1:10 # test input

rollmeanr(X, 2, fill = NA)
## [1]  NA 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5 9.5
```

so does this (no packages):

```
n <- length(X)
c(NA, (X[-1] + X[-n])/2)
## [1]  NA 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5 9.5
```

and this somewhat more general base R approach (also no packages):

```
k <- 2
c(rep(NA, k-1), rowMeans(embed(X, k)))
## [1]  NA 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5 9.5
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for.  If I use rollmean(X, 3, fill=NA), I get                    
          NA  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 NA

Comment: Read the answer again. You forgot the r on the end of rollmeanr.